# How do I include a blank in a datasheet dropdown?

Tags: lookup-column

Using the datasheet view, I have a list setup and one of the columns has a dropdown. I want to include a blank space as one of my choice options.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making the field not required and not providing a default value. This will allow users to delete an existing choice when editing or not supply a value when adding an item.

Comment: The field is not required and I am not providing a default value. If I try to delete an existing choice, I get a red triangle and it says this is not a valid choice.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Choice Column from Column settings and in Value field leave the first line blank i.e. your first choice value is a blank and then have your choices from second line onward. Also make sure there is no value in Default value column. Now, the choice column drop down will have all your choices with first choice as a empty space.

Comment: Anit - I have tried that but as soon as I say Ok - the first line with the blank disappears and it goes back to they way it was. The Default value is blank. FYI - I am on the latest version of SharePoint.

Comment: ok, I tried in SharePoint 2010 and its working fine for me in 2010, don't know if in SharePoint 2013 there is a change in that,,try creating a new column and check...